# How to report execution time of each test in protractor-jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, tdd, e2e-testing

Is there a ready-made way to display execution time of every 'it' block in protractor and jasmine? 
I want to display the execution time of each test wether it failed or succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Install `jasmine-spec-reporter` npm library and add the below code to your `config` file.

```
/* Jasmin specReporter */
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
 jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true, displayDuration: true } }));
```

Hope it helps you